# How to keep all values except "undefined" in deep objects/arrays in JS?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that will check to see if an object or array has a non `undefined` value no matter how deep, and return true if it does and false if not. But this isn't exactly what I want.

Given these as examples:

```js
const arr1 = ["1", 2, ["1", false, ["2", "3", undefined, false]]];
const obj1 = {
    first: "hello",
    last: "world",
    nested: {
        first: "hello",
        last: "world",
        word: undefined,
        falsy: false,
        nested: {
            first: null,
            last: "world",
            word2: undefined,
            falsey: false
        }
    }
}

// new values
const arr1Copy = ["1", 2, ["1", false, ["2", "3", false]]];
const obj1Copy = {
    first: "hello",
    last: "world",
    nested: {
        first: "hello",
        last: "world",
        falsy: false,
        nested: {
            first: null,
            last: "world",
            falsey: false
        }
    }
}
```

I basically want to a new copy of an array or object that has all values except `undefined`. I still want it to retain `false` and `null` values. I tried to modify my current function to work this way, but I can't figure it out. I think I have the recursive function part working, but I can't get it to keep the nested object/arrays at the correct level.

Here is my current function to check that:

```js
const deepCheck = (val) => {
  // check arrays
  if(isArray(val)) { // lodash function isArray
    for (let i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
      if (deepCheck(val[i])) return true
    }
    return
  }
  // check objects
  if(isPlainObject(val)) { // lodash function isPlainObject
    for (const k in val) {
      if (deepCheck(val[k])) return true
    }
    return
  }

  return typeof val !== `undefined`
}
```

Comment: Why not add a reference to the new array variable to the function, and read it, once no more paths are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working, but still trying to think of a way to simplify it while accomplishing the task.

```
function removeUndefined(item) {
    let newItem;
    const itemIsArray = _.isArray(item);
    const itemIsObject = _.isObject(item);
    if (itemIsArray) {
        newItem = [];
    } else if (itemIsObject) {
        newItem = {};
    }

    _.forEach(item, (value, key) => {
        if (_.isArray(value) || _.isObject(value)) {
            // step one level deeper
            if (itemIsArray) {
                newItem.push(removeUndefined(value));
            } else if (itemIsObject) {
                newItem[key] = removeUndefined(value);
            }
        } else {
            if (!_.isUndefined(value)) {
                if (itemIsArray) {
                    newItem.push(value);
                } else if (itemIsObject) {
                    newItem[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    return newItem;
}


console.log(removeUndefined(arr1));
console.log(removeUndefined(obj1));
```

Result:

```
[ '1', 2, [ '1', false, [ '2', '3', false ] ] ]
{
    first: 'hello',
    last: 'world',
    nested: {
        first: 'hello',
        last: 'world',
        falsy: false,
        nested: {
            first: null,
            last: 'world',
            falsey: false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ideally the key wouldn't be name `nested`. It could be any key.

Comment: Oh ok, I took that out, so it will just check for having an object

Comment: I also just removed in-loop type checking for the same variable `item`, so that it just refers to a boolean.

Comment: Also I assume the _ is using lodash, but maybe just clarify that in the answer, well done though, thank you :)